# How do i open ANS files in python?

Tags: python, ansi-escape

Python 2.7.8 (with colorama) doesn't seem to load ANS files correctly.
When i print an ANS file out, the output is blank.

The code is is:
    `o = open("C:\ANSI\DATA\MENU1.AMS", 'r')`
    `print(o)`
Am i forgetting a special character or something?

Comment: You're printing the file handle, **not** its contents - try `print(o.read())`.

Comment: Thank you, i am such an idiot. lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not at all printing the contents of the file

YOU can do it with the help of `read()` function.

Doing it like  `print(o.read())` would work fine.